# How to use span and list tag together correctly

Tags: html, css

So basically there are 3 lines which i am trying to use as unordered list so i enclosed them in ul ,li tags

i want some part of Line 1 to inherit a span tag bold , but using that tag is causing all the  3 lines to inherit that span tag instead of just some part of first line

```
<ul>
<span class="bold"><li class="type1">Ths line is bold and underlined</span> This is continuation of Line 1 but normal text</li>
<li class="type1">This is a normal line</li>
<li class="type1">This is a normal line</li>
</ul>
```

```
.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.type1 {
  padding-left: 1.3em; 
  text-indent: -1.3em;
}

li.type1::before {
  content: "彡 ";
  color: black; 
}
```

**I know some people will recommend a change in the first line of html that i should use span tag later and first use li tag - that indeed fixes issue of all 3 lines inheriting span tag but causes another issue of its own which you can easily check [here](https://jsbin.com/ledovevuta/edit?output)**

Please someone suggest a fix for this

Comment: `<span><li></span></li>` is simply invalid + `li` should be the only child of `ul`

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes sir i am aware , it didn't looked right on just reading.  But i don't know of any alternative approach

Comment: *that indeed fixes issue of all 3 lines inheriting span tag but causes another issue of its own* --> remove inline-block from span, it's not needed

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow that fixed it.  Thanks   i gotta learn more on display attribute.

Comment: Why not just use a strong tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add elements between ul and li tag. A ul Tag has to be followed by an li tag.
Use this structure-

```css
.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.type1 {
  padding-left: 1.3em; 
  /*text-indent: -1.3em;*/
  position:relative;
}

li.type1::before {
  left: 0;
  content: "彡 ";
  color: black; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="type1"><span class="bold">Ths line is bold and underlined</span> This is continuation of Line 1 but normal text</li>
<li class="type1">This is a normal line</li>
<li class="type1">This is a normal line</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that not just fixed the issue but also gave me alternative approach of text indent by using position attribute

Comment: @BadalSingh the approach I was refering to when closing your old question as duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57834197/8620333) that you will find in the first snippet of the first answer in the first duplicate.